# Does the fractional quantum Hall effect always occur when the integer quantum Hall effect occurs?

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

Does the fractional quantum Hall effect always occur when the integer quantum Hall effect occurs? In other words, is there an example of a material where the IQHE can be measured without the "noise" of the FQHE, allowing us to see the idealized IQHE as shown [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Rhoxy.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

The fractional QHE is an effect of the local Coulomb fields of impurities or inhomogeneities of the donator distribution that bind part of the total current locally.  Its probably impossible to produce a donator density as a regular sublattice without disturbations by the third law of thermodynamics.